# Control value getting 'undefined' assigned to it

Tags: angular, forms

I am working on an angular application and I have a form where in there is main question which has "Yes"/"No" answer and based on user selection , if the user selects "Yes" then the sub questions with radio button and input text, get enabled and the user can enter values.
So on ngInit I do subscribe to the changes in value of main Question that way I can enable the controls.

The code is like below:

```
<div>
            <div class="form-field" [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': submitted && formModel.hasError('required','Q4')}">
                <p>4. Are you an entity that is an issuer of securities registered ?</p>
                <div class="radio" *ngFor="let answer of answers">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Q4" formControlName="Q4" ngModel [value]="answer"> {{answer}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-field" [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': submitted && (formModel.hasError('required','Q4a')
                               || formModel.hasError('invalidSECIndexKeyError','Q4a'))}" >
                <p>4a. The relevant SEC Central Index Key number for that party:</p>
                <div class="number">
                    <input type="text" formControlName="Q4a" maxlength="10"
                           (keypress)="validateTheSECKeyPress($event)" required  />
                </div>
                <div class="field-errors" *ngIf="submitted && formModel.get('Q4a').invalid && formModel.get('Q4a').errors">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let error of formModel.get('Q4a').errors | objectEntries">
                        <li>
                            {{ getValidationErrorMessage(error.key, error.value) }}
                        </li>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-field" [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': submitted && formModel.hasError('required','Q4b')}">
                <p>4b. Whether an appropriate committee of that counterparty’s board of directors
                    (or equivalent body) has reviewed and approved the decision to enter into swaps.</p>
                <div class="radio" *ngFor="let answer of answers">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Q4b" formControlName="Q4b" 
                               ngModel [value]="answer"> {{answer}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

and in ngInit i have below code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._formSubscriptions = new Rx.Subscription();

    let Q4sub = this.formModel.get('Q4').valueChanges.subscribe(
        (val) => {
            let ctrl1 = this.formModel.get('Q4a');
            let ctrl2 = this.formModel.get('Q4b');
            if (val === 'Yes') {
                ctrl1.enable();
                ctrl2.enable();
            } else {
                ctrl1.disable();
                ctrl1.reset();
                ctrl2.disable();
                ctrl2.reset();
            }
        }
    );

    this._formSubscriptions.add(Q4sub);
}
```

but what I am seeing is, if the form preloads with values from database and the question Q4 had 'No' value populated and when user tries to change the value to "yes" the other controls get "undefined" value assigned to them and due to this both controls remains disabled. this happens randomly for few records. But other records are fine.

How do I handle these random "undefined" control values?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution but I am not sure if its a good practice to check for undefined value like below

```
if(val === undefined)
{
}
```

or is it better to use if(!val) which checked for undefined?